# Dataflow pipeline and pubsub emulator

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm trying to setup my development environment. Instead of using google cloud pubsub in production, I've been using the pubsub emulator for development and testing. To achieve this I set the following environment variable:

```
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8586
```

This worked for the python google pubsub library but when I switched to using java apache beam for google dataflow, the pipeline still points to production google pubsub. Is there a setting, environment variable or method on the pipeline that I need to set so that the pipeline reads for the local pubsub emulator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution in the PubsubOptions interface, and extending it for my own PipelineOptions implementation. Then using setPubsubRootUrl() to set it to localhost:port of the emulator.

Comment: Ah, It was so simple. stupid me.
  PubsubOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
            .as(PubsubOptions.class);
  
  options.setPubsubRootUrl("http://localhost:8085");

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify this option in a configuration file

```
pubsubRootUrl=http://localhost:8185
```

or via program argument (haven't tested but should also work)

```
-Dexec.args="--pubsubRootUrl=http://localhost:8185"
```

the `http://` is required to conform to Java URL format